# Dog pee on wrong place but only when I'm awake

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I have a 3 months old pug and at first he can roam around the house but noticed he needs to be house trained.

Now he's allowed only in my room where I can monitor him and let him go out if I'll go out.

Now after 2 weeks, he uses my bathroom for pooping 9/10 times but peeing is a different case.

If I wake up from night or just a short nap, I can see he uses the bathroom for both poop and pee when he needs it so I know he knows where to go by now.

But when I'm working on my computer and he needs to go, he'd pee beside or behind me.

Tried to find explanations on Google but answers are generic house training articles.

Why does he do it and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

The same as with people / children, this is a rebel behavior (i.e. knows the rules but breaks them intentionally).

Rebel behaviors, most of the time, have only one purpose: to attract attention. In your case, especially that the pug is very young (only 3 months old), he wants your attention. I assume there are no other "interactive" attractions in your house, which he can use.

One possible solution is to spend more time with him, when you are around and awake. Don't forget him while you cook / use your computer / clean / ... Just take some occasional breaks from whatever you do and entertain him. I expect (no scientific measurements done) that even 5 min in an hour should do the trick. Perhaps the little one even "tells" you when he needs your attention more" barking, showing you that he has a ball, dragging something on the floor - you will have to analyze the specifics of your particular case.

Also, I find it plausible that the dog actually understands things better than expected, because he does not expect your attention while you sleep - he uses the "lawful" bathroom.

Comment: I suppose I'll try giving him more attention. He has lots of toys now if you can consider them as interactive attractions because he gets bored quick! he changes from one to another within <5mins.